# Calling my evil REST service from AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest

So, i've spent a day googling and hammering my keyboard but nothing seem to help.

I have a simple REST service in Servicestack that returns this

```
{"Name":"ANDERSON, ALICE"}
```

I'm trying to call it from my service like this

```
  .service('Myservice', function Myservice($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:61721/britta/:Id',
    {Id: "@Id"},
    {
        show: { method: 'GET',  params: { }, headers: {'Accept':'application/json'}}
 });
 });
```

I call this one from a simple controller, with hardcoded values

```
   $scope.submit = function (form){
   $scope.result= Myservice.show({}, {'Id' : '1'});
   alert(JSON.stringify($scope.result));
```

But my form is empty

```
<div class="resultpanel" ng-show="result">
<p> Name: {{ result.Name }} </p>
```

If I modify my code to return the simple JSON it works, so I guess I'm lousy at writing services?
And that JSON.stringify only tells me

```
{"Id":"1","$promise":{},"$resolved":false}
```

whatever that means..

EDIT:
  this works in Pythonscript, can't really understand why wrapping the answer into a "promise" will help me?

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://localhost:61721/britta/1/?format=json'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print response
...
{"Name":"ANDERSON, ALICE"}
```

***SOLVED***
Actually I had two problems. The first, as Daniel pointed out was that Angular got a promise and not a JSON object. When I solved that, I still had problems which turned out to be about allowing cross domain origins. When I set that up, all my services handed correct promises over to me nicely and peace came to the realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting an immediate result from your resource call, Instead you are getting something that is called a *promise*, so you should use it in the following way

```
$scope.resultPromise= Myservice.show({Id : '1'});

resultPromise.$promise.then(function (value, responseHeaders) {
    console.log('All ok lets continue');
    $scope.result = value;
    alert($scope.result);
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Something went wrong');
});
```

---

If you look at what you were getting till now (*"$promise":{},"$resolved":false*) is a promise that was not resolved yet, you should google a bit about about angualrjs promises

---

Check out the following [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SFHLkqIQP4Jtjoib7nJY?p=preview) I did that uses resource with REST an all

Comment: Thanks for answering, so .NET ServiceStack doesn't return standard JSON? (never used it before). I'll tried your code but always end up in "error", will google some more!!

Comment: I don't know what your rest returns to you , its up to you to decide, the key here is to understand that angularjs return you something called promise - its not an immediate response from your rest... but a promise for a one...

Comment: Promises sound a lot better then evals. I think I understand it, but unfortunately I only end up in "error" anyway, need to google up some examples on how to find out why $scope.resultPromise.$promise.then is evil. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for trying, i still fall back to the "error" though. I'll give it one last try with some new code from scratch, or I'll guess we'll just give up on Angular.

Comment: I wrote an app from scratch with your code, got resultPromise not defined.. if I change to $scope.resultPromise.$promise I get stuck in the "error".. as usual

Comment: i just edited my answer with a live example of how to use the resource /rest etc...

Comment: Thanks again, would gladly buy you a pizza some day. I tried your code with my service and got the alert "httpResponse: object Object", weird

Comment: does `alert($scope.result.Name);` give you the name? anyway you can place a brake point in browser console to inspect that object

Comment: Nope, the code never enters that part so it will never assign anything to $scope.result, or alert 'origin' in your code. AngularJs and ServiceStack is not a good match from what I understand..

Comment: Not familiar with *ServiceStack* but take a look at my example how to handle the resource/REST in angularJS

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did. unfortunately it won't work with my service, I'll find something else. Thank you

Comment: I downloaded a Ms WebAPI Rest example and used your plunkr code to call it. It did'n t manage to parse that code either, got stuck in httpResponse: [object Object]. Will need to write my client in something else i guess, but Thanks for trying to help

Comment: you should place a breakpoint in your browser console on that line that alerts the *httpResponse: [object Object]* and inspect that object, see if it contains relevant data

Comment: Nope, only data:"" .. actually, just struck me. I've tried three REST services running on localhost and they all failed from my Angular Webapp,(not from pyscript though).. will try to put something on openShift

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for you? :

```
$http({
    cache: false,
    url: http://localhost:61721/britta/1,
    method: "GET"
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: instead of return $resource in my service you mean? Will try